# Memory allocation of Array

Tags: java, arrays, memory

If I declare array of Strings like, 
`String []str = new String[3]; //line 1`

It creates one reference(pointer) in stack for string array, but still I need to do `str[0] = new String();` to initialize String in array.

I understand that *line 1* just allocates memory to pointers that will be used to point to Strings in array.

My doubt is, are these references(pointers) allocated memory in heap(most probably yes, because **new** is used), if yes, than why?

Comment: There is no pointers in `Java`

Comment: references are nothing just pointers, there are pointers in java, but pointers can not be manipulated in java

Comment: We never use word `pointers` with `Java`. There are more things than you think about `pointers`. You need to read this carefully.http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an array of strings like, `String[] str = new String[3];`, you are not just creating **a single reference to the** array. Rather you are creating **an array of references for each string**. In the above example, **an array of three references** will be created. All these three references will be created in the stack itself. Note that in JAVA, all primitive types and references will be created in stack itself. After the above statement, all the three string references will be pointing to a special **null** object.

Now, when you start creating the actual string objects using `str[0] = new String();`, then the new string object itself will be created in the HEAP. And **the first reference** in the array of references points to the newly created string object.

Instead, if you just say `new String()`, with out any assignment on the left side, the new string object will be created in the HEAP, and there will not be any reference to it. That means, we can not access the newly created string object in subsequent steps.

Let us say, you again do something like `str[0] = null;`, then the reference again points back to null, and we will not have any reference to the string object that we created earlier. In other words, we can not access the string object any more.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no pointers. But if you had used an `Object` with a default `toString()`, *like an array!*, you'd get something like a reference address

```
int[] test = new int[] {1};
int[] test2 = new int[] {1};
System.out.printf("%s %s%n", test, test2);
```

Which outputs (*here* but your's will have two different address, *very probably*, every time)

```
[I@15db9742 [I@6d06d69c
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the array will be on the stack. The array will be on the heap. If you add new *references* to the array, then the references will be on the heap (as the array itself is on the heap). Provided there are no other references pointing to the same String.

PS : Since the introduction of [Escape Analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html) from Java6U23, the allocation could be done / moved to the stack itself.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, primitive objects (int, long, byte, etc) along with array references (String[], int[], etc) would be on the stack. Any complex objects (ex. String, ArrayList, Cat, Dog, Foo, Double, Long (notice the capitalised D and L in Double and Long vs the smaller ones) etc), would reside on the heap.